# Matlab rename elements of struct array

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have a struct array, `Links` as follows:

```
==================
src   dest    type
==================
dev_1  sw_1    S
d_2  sw_3    S
ev_4  sw_2    S
DND    sw_1    Y
sw_3    DND    Y
sw_1    dev_1  S
sw_2    ev_4  S
sw_2    sw_1   D
...
```

EDIT:

I need to change the above struct array by replacing all the elements other than `DND` and `sw_*` elements to RBR while leaving `DND` and `sw_*` fields as it is, that is:

```
==================
src   dest    type  
==================
RBR    sw_1    S
RBR    sw_3    S
RBR    sw_2    S
DND    sw_1    Y
sw_3    DND    Y
sw_1    RBR  S
sw_2    RBR S
sw_2    sw_1   D
...
```

I'd like to know the quickest way to achieve this. My thoughts were to do the following:

```
idxC_src = strfind({links.src}, 'SW')
% filter our the fields having SW
idxE_src = find((cellfun('isempty', idxC)))
% do the same for links.dest as well.
```

But there is probably an easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to update the cell array of strings:

```
% Generate sample data
Links = struct('src',{'dev_1', 'dev_2', 'dev_4', 'DND', 'sw_2', 'sw_2'}, ...
               'dest',{'sw_2', 'sw_2', 'DND', 'dev_1', 'dev_2', 'dev_4'}, ...
               'type', {'S', 'S', 'S', 'Y', 'S', 'D'} ...
               );


fieldstoupdate = {'src', 'dest'};
for ii = 1:numel(fieldstoupdate)
    fname = fieldstoupdate{ii};
    if isfield(Links, fname)
        % Find where string does not start with 'DND' or 'sw_' followed byone or more digits
        tmp = regexprep({Links.(fname)}, '^(?!DND|sw_\d+).*', 'RBR');

        % Assign the resulting cell array back to Links
        [Links(:).(fname)] = tmp{:};
    end
end
```

Which for the sample struct:

```
  src       dest      type
_______    _______    ____

'dev_1'    'sw_2'     'S' 
'dev_2'    'sw_2'     'S' 
'dev_4'    'DND'      'S' 
'DND'      'dev_1'    'Y' 
'sw_2'     'dev_2'    'S' 
'sw_2'     'dev_4'    'D'
```

Gives us the following:

```
 src       dest     type
______    ______    ____

'RBR'     'sw_2'    'S' 
'RBR'     'sw_2'    'S' 
'RBR'     'DND'     'S' 
'DND'     'RBR'     'Y' 
'sw_2'    'RBR'     'S' 
'sw_2'    'RBR'     'D'
```

Note that I have also used [Dynamic Field Referencing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) to make the loop simpler.

---

You can also utilize a [table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) and reassign the values directly.

Using the same example structure:

```
Links = struct2table(Links);

fieldstoupdate = {'src', 'dest'};
for ii = 1:numel(fieldstoupdate)
    fname = fieldstoupdate{ii};
    if ismember(fname, Links.Properties.VariableNames)
        Links.(fname) = regexprep(Links.(fname), '^(?!DND|sw_\d+).*', 'RBR');
    end
end
```

Which provides the same result.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot use `regexprep` since there are a couple of sources which do not match `dev_*` too. That is I should not change the ones starting with `sw` and `DND` but all the others.

Comment: That's significantly different than the question you asked, and it does not preclude the use of regular expressions. I would recommend that you edit your post to ask the question you actually want the answer to.

Comment: Sorry about not being precise. I've edited my post now.